# Almost everywhere derivative of integral function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I=[a,b]$, $g \in L^1(I)$ and define $v(x):=\displaystyle \int_a^xg(y)dy$

> Show that $v$ is $AC(I)$ and that $v'=g$ almost everywhere

Is my approach correct? Do you know a better (shorter/simpler/more elegant) proof, supposed mine is correct?

1. $v \in AC$: by the fundamental theorem of calculus $v$ is $AC(I)$, since it is the integral of an $L^1$ function. Also, $v$ is almost everywhere differentiable, because it is $BV$.
2. $v'=g$ almost everywhere: for $x \in (a,b)$ and a small enough $h>0$: $$\left | \frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h} - g(x)\right |\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}|g(y)-g(x)|dy=*$$
   Call $G_x(y)=g(y)-g(x)\in L^1(I)$. For every $\delta$ choose a continuous function $g_\delta$ that well approximates $g$ in $L^1(I)$ and call $G_x^\delta(y)=g_\delta(y)-g(x)$, so that $||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1(I)}\rightarrow 0$ as $\delta\rightarrow 0$. Therefore, for every $\delta>0$: $$*\leq \frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}+\frac{1}{h}||G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}=\\\frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}+\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}|g_\delta(y)-g(x)|dy\leq\\\frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}+\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}|g_\delta(y)-g_\delta(x)|dy+\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}|g_\delta(x)-g(x)|dy=\\\frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}+\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}|g_\delta(y)-g_\delta(x)|dy+|g_\delta(x)-g(x)|=*$$ We can choose $h$ small enough to have, by uniform continuity: $$*\leq \frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}+h+|g_\delta(x)-g(x)|=*$$ Lastly, using the $L^1$ convergence of $g_\delta$ to $g$ (which yields the $L^1$ convergence of $G_x^\delta$ to $G_x$ and also the a.e. convergence of $g_\delta$ to $g$), we have, for almost every $x$: $$*\leq 3h$$ So, by further specifying $x$ such  the limit  $\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{v(x+h)-v(x)}{h}$ exists, we get the result.

---

**Edit** (fixing the second part)

Tying in on the second last passage, since $h>0$:

$$ \frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1([x,x+h])}+h+|g_\delta(x)-g(x)|\leq \frac{1}{h}||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1(I)}+h+|g_\delta(x)-g(x)|$$

Then the fact that $g_\delta \rightarrow g$ in ${L^1(I)}$ ensures the result (the $L^1$ norm is estimated by choosing a small enough $\delta$ so as to get $||G_x-G_x^\delta||_{L^1(I)}<h^2$).

Comment: There exist non-constant function which are differentiable a.e. with derivative $0$ a.e. and these are not AC. So your answer to 1) is wrong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is it correct now?

Comment: No. It is still wrong for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for then first part is wrong. FTC is not applicable here.

By a well know fact in measure theory integrability of $g$ implies that given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\int_E |g(x)|dx<\epsilon$ whenever $m(E) <\delta$ (where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure).  Now if $(a_i,b_i): 1\leq i \leq n$ is a  finite collection of disjoint intervals with total length less than $\delta$ it follows immediately that $\sum |f(b_i)-f(a_i)| <\epsilon $ (by taking $E=\bigcup_i (a_i,b_i)$. Hence $f$ is AC.

In the second part you have no control over $\frac  1 h \|G_x-G_x^{\delta}\|_{|L^{1}[x.x+h]}$ since the convergence of $\|G_x-G_x^{\delta}\|_{|L^{1}[x,x+h]}$ to $0$ as $\delta \to 0$ is not uniform in  $h$.
The second part is a standard theorem called Lebesgue's differentiation theorem and it can be found on Wikipedia.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions, I meant this fundamental theorem of calculus. $v$ is of the form at (3)

Comment: You cannot call that theorem FTC. It should be called Lebesgue's FTC. Secondly I doubt if it is legitimate to use that theorem here. You are assuming what you are asked to prove.

Comment: @Leonardo Your proof for the second part is wrong. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and for checking the second part of the proof. I added a line to further motivate the last passage: shouldn't it be fine now?